# Most frequently copy/pasted clips

Tags: vim

Are there a feature for showing most frequently copy/pasted clips?

That information might be useful for productivity, to see, which clips may be stored in registers, for example.

Comment: `:registers` outputs the contents of the registers to the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing built-in apart from the *numbered registers* `"0` to `"9`, which hold the last 10 yanks and deletes.

However, you could build your own plugin that occasionally samples the register contents (e.g. on `CursorHold` or `FocusLost` events), and maintains a statistic. To get exact values, you'd need to overload all related yank and delete commands (as plugins like *YankRing* do).